# Start django app as service

Tags: python, django, ubuntu

I want to create service that will be start with ubuntu and will have ability to use django models etc.. 
This service will create thread util.WorkerThread and wait some data in main.py

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
   bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

How I can to do this. I just don't know what I need to looking for.

If you also can say how I can create ubuntu autostart service with script like that, please tell me )

P.S. all django project run via uwsgi in emperor mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, that is answer - https://www.raspberrypi-spy.co.uk/2015/10/how-to-autorun-a-python-script-on-boot-using-systemd/

In new versions ubuntu services .conf in /etc/init fail with error `Unable to connect to Upstart: Failed to connect to socket /com/ubuntu/upstart: Connection refused`

But services works using systemd

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way in my opinion is create a script and run on crontab.

First of all create a script to start your django app.

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /path/to your/virtual environment  #path to your virtual environment
. bin/activate  #Activate your virtual environment
cd /path/to your/project directory  #After that go to your project directory
python manage.py runserver  #run django server
```

Save the script and open crontab with the command:

```
crontab -e
```

Now edit the crontab file and write on the last line:

```
@reboot path/to/your/script.sh
```

This way is not the best but the easiest, if you are not comfortable with Linux startup service creation.

I hope this help you :)

Comment: My project running with uwsgi, but I have some script in project which run looped thread to wait commands and must use django project's models... I need run this script as service I think.

Comment: @MaksimZarechnyi yeah, in that case you need to use as service.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [supervisord](http://supervisord.org/). It is much easier than daemonizing python script.

Config it something like this:

```
[program:watcher]
command = /usr/bin/python /path/to/main.py
stdout_logfile = /var/log/main-stdout.log
stdout_logfile_maxbytes = 10MB
stdout_logfile_backups = 5
stderr_logfile = /var/log/main-stderr.log
stderr_logfile_maxbytes = 10MB
stderr_logfile_backups = 5
```

Comment: And /path/to/main.py script in this case will be able to use django project's models? If I run script in console, it don't see projects packages.

Comment: You need to replace /usr/bin/python with path of your virtualenv's python. Activate virtualenv and type `echo $VIRTUAL_ENV/bin/python`.